# How to add spaces automatically in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

Is there any way to automatically add spaces in Xcode? For example: `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)` turns into: `for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )`. This feature is available in vs code and I'm used to it, so I was wondering if there was some way to do it.

[image]

Comment: When you have your source file open, does `Cmd+A` (select all lines) and `Ctrl+i` (indent) re-indent for you?  Or if you need more powerful reformatting, there's the clang-format addon for Xcode, https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode